# pgp_sym_decrypt using with select query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, encryption

I want to select all data from a table (all data in table were encrypted) in postgresql database. But can't get all data.Query only works with condition. This query works. `select pgp_sym_decrypt(name::bytea,'code'), pgp_sym_decrypt(surname::bytea,'code'), pgp_sym_decrypt(context::bytea,'code') from schema.table_name where id=1;`

But I want to use this query :  `select pgp_sym_decrypt(name::bytea,'code'), pgp_sym_decrypt(surname::bytea,'code'), pgp_sym_decrypt(context::bytea,'code') from schema.table_name;`

How can I get all data?

Comment: Sp What happens?

Comment: for example, Table have 5 encrypted records. I want to get all records with decryption. Postgresql throw error: Wrong key or corrupt data. my query(select pgp_sym_decrypt(name::bytea,'code'), pgp_sym_decrypt(surname::bytea,'code'), pgp_sym_decrypt(context::bytea,'code') from schema.table_name;)

Comment: So at least one record has a different password, or the data is corrupt. You can go through the records one by one until you find it.

Comment: It looks like you may have corrupted your data by storing bytea data in a text field.

Comment: it works one by one correct, but for all doesn't work